# Trying to calculate the average of a float list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I don't know if I'm going about getting the `float`values the right way but this is what I have so far.

```
grades_file = open('grades.txt', 'r')

# Print Header & spacer
print('Name' + '\t\tGrade')
print('---------------------')

# Read lines & store grades
for file_lines in grades_file:
    lines = file_lines.rstrip('\n')

    num_list = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", lines)
    grades = [float(num) for num in num_list]
    average = statistics.mean(grades)

    print(lines)
    print(average)
```

Now I'm trying to get it to print what's in the file and print the average of the numbers separately but this is what I'm getting.

```
Output:

    Name        Grade
---------------------
   Mickey,Mouse 90.0
   90.0
   Jane,Doe     50.0
   50.0
   Minnie,Mouse 95.0
   95.0
   Donald,Duck  80.0
   80.0
   Daffy,Duck   70.0
   70.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
The contents of `num_list`:

```
['90.0']
['50.0']
['95.0']
['80.0']
```

When I try to just print `num_list` it shows up similar to printing average.

Contents of the input file:

```
Mickey,Mouse 90.0
Jane,Doe     50.0
Minnie,Mouse 95.0
Donald,Duck  80.0
Daffy,Duck   70.0
```

Comment: Can you print the contents of num_list? Assuming num_list contains a list of numbers, your code should work properly. It would be helpful to have a sample input file as well.

Comment: Edited to add contents of file and num_list

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I don't know why but I had to put the grade average in a separate function

```
def grade_avg():
    grades_file = open('grades.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = grades_file.read()

    num_list = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", file_contents)
    grades = [float(num) for num in num_list]
    average = mean(grades)

    print('Average Grade:', average)
```

It seems like a long workaround but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `regex` function inside the `for loop` of each line of the file. So you are calculating the average of a single number.

You need to calculate the average first, and then print each line contents:

```
import re
import statistics

with open('grades.txt', 'r') as grades_file:
    # Print Header & spacer
    print('Name' + '\t\tGrade')
    print('---------------------')

    num_list = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", grades_file.read()) #get all grades from file
    grades = list(map(float, num_list)) #convert to float
    average = statistics.mean(grades) #compute average
    # Read lines & store grades
    grades_file.seek(0) #reset file position
    for file_lines in grades_file:
        lines = file_lines.rstrip('\n')
        print(lines)
        print(average)
```